# Issue with back up of serialized objects - Android

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-framework

I have an app in which I am maintaining serialized objects in a file. When I try to backup using "adb backup" I am getting a NULL pointer exception in framework. I am assuming something is wrong with my code.

```
mFileOutputStream =  mContext.openFileOutput(vfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(mFileOutputStream);
oos.writeObject( smsBackup );
oos.flush();
oos.close();
mFileOutputStream.close();
```

smsBackup is the object which holds a copy of all messages on the device. As far as I can tell, there seems to be no issue in the way I am serializing the object. On issuing adb backup, control goes to

```
void onFullBackup(FullBackupDataOutput data){
BackupSMS smsBackup = new QualcommBackupSMS(this, SMS);
    smsBackup.performBackup(); //Above snippet is implemented as part of this.
    super.onFullBackup(data); //Exception is coming here.
}
```

This method is overridden on top of BackupAgent.

Stacktrace is follows:

```
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268): java.lang.NullPointerException
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:856)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDir(ContextImpl.java:839)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:210)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at android.app.backup.BackupAgent.onFullBackup(BackupAgent.java:297)
D/BackupServiceBinder(1268):    at com.qualcomm.backupagent.BackupAgent.onFullBackup(QualcommBackupAgent.java:79)
```

From some research on this problem I found this [NullPointerException (etc) from Parcel.readException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858320/nullpointerexception-etc-from-parcel-readexception) but nothing more than that. I have used this same routine to backup files where serialization was not involved without any issue which makes me think that the cause of exception is somehow related to serialization. Any clues as to where I can start looking for this NullPointerException?

PS: I have spent a lot of time trying to find the cause of exception in the code and out of desperation I am putting out the question here. Just in case anyone thinks that I am putting out the question without giving it a fair fight.

Comment: So does it work if you remove the extra code in the `onFullBackup()` method?

Comment: @corsair992 Yes it works but then I am not doing what i intend to i.e taking the backup.

Comment: After a lot more attempts in trying to fix this, I found that the problem persists irrespective of whether I use serialization or not. 

This issue could be related to this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62119&q=parcel.readexception&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: I finally came to know of the cause of the problem. I was running this app on an emulator without sdcard image. Apparently, it was trying to write something there (although that is not my intention). After created a virtual device with sdcard image, this problem was resolved.