# How to avoid IllegalStateException in JobScheduler?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

We observe a rare IllegalStateException inside JobScheduler implementation when JobScheduler is accessed within Application.onCreate() method.
I wonder if this is a platform flaw?

We are observing this crash on our users devices.
Almost all of them are Android 5 and 5.1, but one crash happened on Android 6 (Samsung Galaxy S5 Duos).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1711)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1653)
  at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule (IJobScheduler.java:158)
  at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule (JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
  at yo.host.job.a.a (SourceFile:237)
  at yo.widget.WidgetController.b (SourceFile:92)
  at yo.host.Host.q (SourceFile:680)
  at yo.host.Host.onCreate (SourceFile:505)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1032)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5970)
```

Source code

```
int jobId = 1;
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(
    jobId,
    new ComponentName(
        Host.geti().getPackageName(),
        WeatherJobService.class.getName()
    )
);

builder.setPersisted(true);//Restart the job after reboot.
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);

PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
bundle.putString(WeatherJobService.EXTRA_LOCATION_ID, locationId);
bundle.putString(WeatherJobService.EXTRA_REQUEST_ID, requestId);
bundle.putString(WeatherJobService.EXTRA_CLIENT_ITEM, clientItem);
builder.setExtras(bundle);

int errorCode = getJobScheduler().schedule(builder.build());
```

Comment: Do you mean JobScheduler is created within Application#onCreate() ?

Comment: Technically, the system is creating JobScheduler. 
This is what we are doing in Application.onCreate()

myJobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
myJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858320/nullpointerexception-etc-from-parcel-readexception. At least, that question explains why the stack trace above is so uninformative.

Comment: Considered including your SourceFile... or just ANY code at all, to see broader context, because.... what is builder.build()? I just mean this could help anyone to answer your question ;)

Comment: Thanks, Piotr. I have added a portion of code where the Job is scheduled. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

You might be experiencing the exception described here:
https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/issues/202

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1674)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1619)
  at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:158)
  at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
```

In which case you'd want to avoid scheduling more than 100 jobs.

Answer (score -2):

Framework Job Scheduler supports above API level 21. 
Please go through the link below [intelligent job scheduling](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Comment: Job Scheduler API supports API 21 and later.
You just stated the opposite, why?